# UIImagePickerController does not work correctly with uipagecontrol and uitabbar

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uiimagepickercontroller, uitabbar, uipagecontrol

I am trying to open UIImagePickerController from 3 different view controllers. but the problem is that this 3 view controllers are bind together as i am using a pagecontroller (to swipe between these 3 view controllers) and a uitabbar as a parent of these 3 view controllers. So whenever i tried to open UIImagePickerController the page controller and tabbar still covers the bottom part so i can not take a picture.

Can anyone please help me about this? I tried in google but no good solutions though. If my problem is not clear to anyone please ask. I will try to make it make it simpler as much as i can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you present the image picker from self, like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

If so, you should try:

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

(the picker will then be in the same context as the tabBarController)